# Magento Frontend shows X items in one category, but most are not visible!

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, indexing

Magento 1.9.3 - I cannot update because of plugins I am using.

-I have about 900 items on my website.

-17 of them in a Subcategory.

-The frontend shows that there are 17 items in the category - but only 5 shows on page 1 and 4 on page 2 (when sorted by 12 items per page. If I increase to 24 items per page, I see only the first 4.)

-If I disable all items and then re-enable all items, they show up briefly but then disappear again!

-Items are visible, enabled, in stock, in the correct category, added to the website.... Same settings as the other items on the page that all work fine.

I have been doing some searching some people are saying it has something to do with the Indexer? How do I fix it? Any ideas??

Thanks!

Comment: Is indexing working fine ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that more? 
If I add new products, they show up... All the other categories seem to work fine. Just seems to be this one category...

Comment: based on your details, it looks like data issue.

Comment: How do I go about fixing it? 
www.WesternPetSupply.ca is my site - if that helps. The category in question is Dog/Toys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will see page source (HTML) of that category page.
You will find this
`<a href="http://www.westernpetsupply.ca/dog/toys/dogit-design-gumi-dental-dog-toy-chew-clean-large.html?___SID=U" title="Dogit Design Gumi Dental Dog Toy - Chew &amp; Clean - Large" class="product-image"><img src="<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 18416 bytes) in <b>/home/overkill452/public_html/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php</b> on line <b>74</b><br />`

It is PHP memory issue on product "Dogit Design Gumi Dental Dog Toy", either upload a smaller filesize image or increase php memory_limit in .ini file to sort this issue.

Comment: Thanks! Increased the limit and it works! Turns out I was missing php5.ini... Copied my settings over and it's all good now. Thanks a bunch! :)